# Perform file upload via PUT method by HTMX

Tags: cgi, put, htmx

Have simple CGI/HTMX utilizing system and need to uploading images to server script via PUT method. Trying something like this, but have no luck.

```
<input id="new_area" type="file" name="mapfile" hx-put="cgi-bin/upload.pl/map.png">
```

I am able to successfully upload files from command line, so expect the problem not lying on server part.

```
curl.exe -u "user:passwd" -T "c:\work\map.png" "map.png"
```

Could someone kick me to right direction? Unfortunatelly have zero experiance with javascript :-/

Answer (score 4):

To upload a file you also need to set the encoding to `multipart/form-data` with the [`hx-encoding` attribute](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-encoding/):

```
<input id="new_area" 
       type="file" 
       name="mapfile" 
       hx-put="cgi-bin/upload.pl/map.png" 
       hx-encoding="multipart/form-data" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly got this one working. HTMX can`t made plain PUT request (application/octet-stream) without additional JS code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload File with htmx and HTTP PUT using Content-Type: application/octet-stream</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org/dist/htmx.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload File with htmx and HTTP PUT using Content-Type: application/octet-stream</h1>
    <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="fileInput">Select a file:</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file">
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
    </form>
    
    <script>
        function uploadFile() {
            const form = document.getElementById("uploadForm");
            const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
            const file = fileInput.files[0];
            
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("PUT", "cgi-bin/upload.pl");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            xhr.send(file);
            
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 201) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        alert("File uploaded successfully!");
                    } else {
                        console.error(xhr.statusText);
                        alert("File upload failed!");
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```